# Error #2025 with my memory game AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

I've been busy with creating a memory game (card matching), but I've come across a bug which I have to solve before wednesday as it is a project for my school.

I've tried alot of ways to try and fix this problem, but as this is the first AS3 script that I have ever written I don't know a way to solve it.

The error occurs when I match 1 pair of cards and the timer runs out of time or you win.

Detailed error report:

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

```
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at main/lose()[C:\Users\Remy\Desktop\Schoolmap\FLASH\memory1_0\main.as:253]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

And here is my oh so sloppy script ;)

```
package  
    {
        // hier import ik de benodigde items.
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.SimpleButton;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.TimerEvent;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.text.TextFormat;
        import flash.utils.Timer;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;

        /**
         * @author Remy&Mark
         */

        public class main extends MovieClip
        {
         hier initialize ik de var's.
            var kaart1:MovieClip;
            var kaarten:Array; // ARRAY is een table.
            var pause_timer:Timer; // Timer voor tijd dat kaarten terug worden gedraaid.
            var kaart1open:Boolean; // benodige booleans en nummers
            var kaart2open:Boolean;
            var kaart1value:Number;
            var kaart2value:Number;
            var kaart1id:Number;
            var kaart2id:Number;
            var cardsRemoved:Number;// einde
            var button:Sprite;// dit is de button
            var values:Array;  //just declare it here, instead of initializing it here
            var startknop:MovieClip = new startKnop(); // maakt de startknop
            var tryAgain:MovieClip = new taKnop(); // try again.
            var score:TextField = new TextField(); // score textfield
            var result:TextField = new TextField(); // WIN of LOSE.
            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
            var streak:Number;
            var bonus:Number;
            var klok:MovieClip = new clock();
            var gameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,8); 
            var retry:Boolean = false; // dit duidt aan of het voor het eerst begint of dat het wordt geretried.
            var win_timer:Timer;
            //einde

            public function main()
            {
                // dit maakt de startknop
                startknop.x = 100;
                startknop.y = 200;
                startknop.buttonMode = true;
                startknop.useHandCursor = true;
                startknop.mouseChildren = false;
                addChild(startknop);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
                // einde
            }

            // deze code word opgeroepen om de game op te zetten en sommige variables goed in te stellen.
            private function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                gameTimer.reset();
                result.text = "";
                values = new Array(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10);
                bonus = 0;
                streak = 0;
                if (retry == false)
                {
                    removeChild(startknop);
                } else {
                    removeChild(tryAgain);
                }
                // score
                score.x = 250;
                score.y = 30;
                score.width = 250;
                score.selectable = false;
                score.text = "Score: 0";
                //score.
                format.size = 40;
                score.setTextFormat(format);
                addChild(score);
                // einde
                // game klok
                klok.x = 625;
                klok.y = 100;
                addChild(klok);
                gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, lose);
                gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
                gameTimer.start();
                // einde
                legKaarten();
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,startGame);
            }

            // Hier worden de kaarten op het bord gelegd en krijgen ze een random variable.
            private function legKaarten() 
            {
                cardsRemoved = 0;
                kaart1open = false;
                kaart2open = false;
                kaart1value = 0;
                kaart2value = 0;
                kaart1id = 0;
                kaart2id = 0;
                kaarten = new Array(); // je roept hier een lege Array(table) op.
                for (var i:int = 0; i <= 17; i++ ) // (int)eger is een afgerond getal. ( geen decimalen)
                {
                    var real:int = i; 
                    var kolom:int = i;
                    var rij:int = 0;
                    kaarten.push(new Kaart1());
                    addChild(kaarten[i]);
                    kaarten[i].stop();
                    // hier worden de kolommen en rijen ingesteld.
                    if ( real > 5&&real <= 11)
                    {
                        rij++;
                        kolom = i - 6;
                    } 
                    if ( real > 11)
                    {
                        rij = rij + 2;
                        kolom = i - 12;
                    }
                    //einde
                    var randIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (values.length - 1)) // hier worden de values geconfigureerd
                    kaarten[i].id = i;
                    kaarten[i].value = values[randIndex]; // dit geeft een kaart een random value uit de Array.
                    values.splice(randIndex, 1);
                    kaarten[i].x = 200+(kolom * 80);
                    kaarten[i].y = 100 + (rij * 150);
                    kaarten[i].width = 75;
                    kaarten[i].height = 125;
                    kaarten[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, omdraaien);
                }
            }

            // deze functie draait de kaarten om om te kijken of de kaarten matchen.
            private function omdraaien(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                  var geklikteKaart:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip; //e.target is de klik target.
                if (geklikteKaart.currentFrame == 1 && kaart1open == false)
                {
                    if (kaart1open == false)
                    {
                        geklikteKaart.gotoAndStop(geklikteKaart.value);
                        kaart1open = true;
                        kaart1value = geklikteKaart.value;
                        kaart1id = geklikteKaart.id;
                    }
                }
                else if(geklikteKaart.currentFrame == 1 && kaart1open == true && kaart2open == false)
                {
                    geklikteKaart.gotoAndStop(geklikteKaart.value);
                    kaart2open = true;
                    kaart2value = geklikteKaart.value;
                    kaart2id = geklikteKaart.id;
                }
                if (kaart1open == true && kaart2open == true && kaart1value == kaart2value)
                {
                    pause_timer = new Timer(250, 1);
                    pause_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeKaarten);
                    pause_timer.start();
                }
                else if (kaart1open == true && kaart2open == true && kaart1value != kaart2value)
                {
                    pause_timer = new Timer(250, 1);
                    pause_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, resetKaarten);
                    pause_timer.start();
                }
            }
            private function removeKaarten(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                removeChild(kaarten[kaart1id]);
                removeChild(kaarten[kaart2id]);
                streak ++;
                cardsRemoved ++;
                kaart1open = false;
                kaart2open = false;
                kaart1value = 0;
                kaart2value = 0;
                kaart1id = 0;
                kaart2id = 0;
                if (streak > 1)
                {
                    bonus = bonus + 50;
                }
                if (cardsRemoved == 9)
                {
                    gameTimer.stop();
                    win_timer = new Timer(500, 1);
                    win_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, win);
                    win_timer.start();
                    pause_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, resetKaarten);
                    gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,tick);
                }
                else if (gameTimer.currentCount == 60)
                {
                    gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,tick);
                }
                score.selectable = false;
                score.text = "Score: " + (cardsRemoved * 100 + bonus);
                format.size = 40;
                score.setTextFormat(format);
                //pause_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, removeKaarten);
            }
            private function resetKaarten(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                kaarten[kaart1id].gotoAndStop(1);
                kaarten[kaart2id].gotoAndStop(1);
                kaart1open = false;
                kaart2open = false;
                kaart1value = 0;
                kaart2value = 0;
                kaart1id = 0;
                kaart2id = 0;
                streak = 0;
                pause_timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, resetKaarten);
            }
            private function tick(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                klok.wijzer.rotation += 360 / gameTimer.repeatCount;
            }
            private function lose(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                retry = true;
                removeChild(klok);
                removeChild(score);
                // tekst voor verlies
                result.x = 300;
                result.y = 150;
                result.width = 250;
                result.selectable = false;
                result.text = "YOU SUCK!";
                format.size = 40;
                result.setTextFormat(format);
                addChild(result);
                // einde
                // dit maakt de try again knop.
                tryAgain.x = 100;
                tryAgain.y = 200;
                tryAgain.buttonMode = true;
                tryAgain.useHandCursor = true;
                tryAgain.mouseChildren = false;
                addChild(tryAgain);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
                // einde
                // hier worden de kaarten verwijderd.
                for (var r:int = 0; r < 18; r++)
                {
                    removeChild(kaarten[r]);
                    values.splice(kaarten[r], 1)
                }
                //einde
            }
            private function win(e:TimerEvent):void
            {
                retry = true;
                removeChild(klok);
                removeChild(score);
                // tekst voor verlies
                result.x = 200;
                result.y = 150;
                result.width = 550;
                result.selectable = false;
                result.text = "YOU ARE A WINNER!";
                format.size = 40;
                result.setTextFormat(format);
                addChild(result);
                // einde
                // dit maakt de try again knop.
                tryAgain.x = 100;
                tryAgain.y = 200;
                tryAgain.buttonMode = true;
                tryAgain.useHandCursor = true;
                tryAgain.mouseChildren = false;
                addChild(tryAgain);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
                // einde
                // hier worden de kaarten verwijderd.
                for (var r:int = 0; r < 18; r++)
                {
                    if (kaarten[r].value != null)
                    {
                        removeChild(kaarten[r]);
                        values.splice(kaarten[r], 1)
                    }
                }
                //einde
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When removing a `DisplayObject` from an `DisplayObjectContainer` you will get an error if the object you are trying to remove is `null` or not a child. You need to test for this.

The following example loops through the "karten" array, checks if each object exists and whether it's a child of `this`. If so, it removes the child, otherwise it does nothing before moving to the next item in the array.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < kaarten.length; i++) {
    if (kaarten[i] && this.contains(kaarten[i])) {
        this.removeChild(kaarten[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great this works!
I have tried alot of ways to try this but didn't know .contains existed.

Just a side question though,
What does "this" mean in AS3, is it like the ROOT of the script?

Comment: `this` refers to the current instance of the object where it was called. In your case, `this` means the current instance of the `main` class. If we assume the `main` class is set as the Document Class for the project, it will be accessible from other `DisplayObject` instances that has been added to the display list using the `root` property.

So, if - and only if - `this` is called within your Document Class it will access the same instance as `root`.